# Vertex color values over one

Tags: vertex-colors

Is it possible to paint vertex colors that are higher than one?

Vertex colors [are exposed through the python API as floating point numbers](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.MeshLoopColor.html). If this is how they're stored, they should happily accept any value without clamping to [0-1], even negative values.

Potential uses include per-vertex light emission or material hardness.

Comment: It is probably supported internally, but the UI doesn't seem to allow doing this. At least from my quick look at it, but I don't use vertex paint often. Maybe through scripting or the API you can do that.

Comment: Attempts to modify the brush color (bpy.data.brushes["Draw"].color) with Python seem to instantly clamp it to [0-1]. This is probably impossible without modifying blender.

Comment: In the page you linked to it does say float between 0 and 1 so I guess it's not supported at all

Comment: You can add  a custom vertex float layer as outlined https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_0/bpy.types.Mesh.html?highlight=vertex_layers_float#bpy.types.Mesh.vertex_layers_float  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36710/create-ui-slider-for-each-member-in-a-custom-vertex-layer-floats?s=1|1.3640

Comment: How would that make sense, color-wise? 0 is the lowest-possible value while 1 is the highest-possible value. Setting for example all R,G and B values to one will produce white, all set to zero produce black.

Comment: @metaphor_set Emissive colors can be any positive value--this is why lamps have an 'Energy' property which can be well above one. Literally all that property does is multiply the lamp's color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes vertex colours are exposed as three floating point values, but in the background they are stored as three integers that are clamped to values between 0 and 255. You can see the actual code doing that [here](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_mesh.c;v2.78$656).

This would be a decision made to conserve space, a floating point value uses 4 bytes of RAM while the integer used fits in 1 byte, that saves 9 bytes for each vertex. This leads to being limited to the 16.7 million colours that can be stored in a [24bit RGB image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_%28digital_image%29#RGB_Images) when using vertex painting.

Blender supports image formats that store float values, so you could look at using an image texture to get more variation in your materials.

Comment: But that´s a blender limitation right? what about an fbx or obj?

Comment: @Badjano yes it is how blender stores the data. If fbx or obj export vertex colours as float values they would be clamped to 0-1 when imported into blender, and as blender only holds the 0-1 value it will always export in that range. This still applies with v2.83